# Combine a list of objects with information from a map Dart

Tags: loops, foreach, dart, flutter

I am trying to add information from a map received through an http call to a list of objects in Dart. For example, the list of objects are Tools that have the toollocation property:

```
Tool(
      {this.make,
      this.model,
      this.description,
      this.tooltype,
      this.toollocation,
      this.paymenttype,
      this.userid});
```

I am also using the google distance matrix api to gather the distance from the user that the tool is.

```
Future<DistanceMatrix> fetchDistances() async {
    await getlocation();
    latlongdetails = position['latitude'].toString() +
        ',' +
        position['longitude'].toString();
    print(latlongdetails);
    print('still running');
    final apiresponsepc = await http
        .get(
            'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=$latlongdetails&destinations=$postcodes&key=xxx');
    distanceMatrix =
        new DistanceMatrix.fromJson(json.decode(apiresponsepc.body));
    return distanceMatrix;
  }
```

What I have been doing in the past is calling a future and just getting the distance once I have returned the original results for the tool. However I want to be able to sort the tool results by distance, so I need to iterate through each tool in the list and add the distance for each of them.

So far I have been trying a foreach loop on the tools list:

```
finalresults.forEach((tool){ tool.toollocation = distanceMatrix.elements[0].distance.text;});
```

but clearly this will only add the first distance measurement to every one of the tools.

Is there any way I can iterate through each tool and then add the distance from the distance matrix map? Each distance will be in sequence with each tool in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this with the following code:

```
int number = 0;
    finalresults.forEach((tool) {
      tool.toollocation = distanceMatrix.elements[number].distance.text;
      number = number + 1;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted to do

```
finalResults.forEach((tool) {
  distanceMatrix.elements.forEach((element){
    tool.toolLocation = element.distance.text;
  });
});
```

If `elements` is also a `List` then you can use the `foreach` syntax to iterate through it.

Comment: This is working through the list but unfortunately it appears to be applying the final value in the elements list to every tool in finalresults. I need to add each corresponding distance to each item in finalresults but not sure how to do this. Sorry if this isn't clear.